# How to read txt file with tags in Python?

Tags: python, text

I am a beginner in Python. I have a **text file** like below with thousands of docs(from id=1 to id=10000):

```
<doc id=1>
    <label>1</label>
    <summary>
        I think you are right
    </summary>
    <short_text>
        I think you are right. Because I have once read the book in the same topic.
    </short_text>
</doc>
```

Is there any convenient way to read the text file and store the content in instances?

```
class ShortText:
    def __init__(self, my_id, human_label, summary, short_text):
        self.id = my_id         
        self.human_label = human_label    
        self.summary = summary 
        self.short_text = short_text
    def __str__(self):
        '''
        For printing purposes.
        '''
        return '%d\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (self.id, self.human_label, self.summary, self.short_text)

def load_file(filename):
    #retrieve the original text 
    with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = f.read()
    #how to get values from tags and put it below？
        my_id = 
        human_label = 
        summary = 
        short_text = 
        instances[my_id] = ShortText(my_id, human_label, summary, short_text)
    return instances
```

Comment: Try this link https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-xml-files-in-python/

Comment: You can certainly read and store the raw text. However, it sounds like you want to *parse* the XML after reading the file, for which you need an XML parser of some sort.

Comment: Is it `id=1` or `id="1"`? I believe there is an important difference

Comment: It is id=1. It is a text file, not xml file.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time using stack overflow. I am not familiar with it. I will edit the question back and add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can treat the data like an XML fragment, you can try using the `lxml` library:

**test.py:**

```
from lxml import etree

a = etree.fromstring("<test>Hello</test>")

print a.text
```

**result**

```
>>> python test.py
Hello
```

**reading from a file:**

```
>>> tree = etree.parse(some_file_or_file_like_object)
```

https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-fromstring-function

https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#parser-objects

Answer (score 1):

I have worked it out by BeautifulSoup.

```
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   

class ShortText:
    def __init__(self, my_id, human_label, summary, short_text):
        self.id = my_id         
        self.human_label = human_label    
        self.summary = summary 
        self.short_text = short_text
    def __str__(self):
        '''
        For printing purposes.
        '''
        return '%d\t%d\t%s\t%s' % (self.id, self.human_label, self.summary, self.short_text)

def load_file(filename):
    #retrieve the original text 
    with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = f.read()
    #use beautifulsoup to get tag attributes and elements
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    tags = soup.find_all('doc')
    #store in a dictionary with ShortText Instances as values
    instances = {}
    my_id = 0
    for t in tags:
        human_label = int(t.human_label.get_text())
        summary = t.summary.get_text().replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
        short_text = t.short_text.get_text().replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
        instances[my_id] = ShortText(my_id, human_label, summary, short_text)
        my_id +=1

    return instances
```

Thank you guys!